# Can I plug a powerline adapter into a grounded-in-wall adapter?

Tags: receptacle, adapter

I have one outlet right next to my router and need it for a bunch of other electronics. I currently have a grounded 6 outlet in-wall adapter plugged in. It is not a surge protector, just an outlet. Will a powerline adapter work through this or does it need to be plugged in directly to the outlet?

Example of the adapter I'm talking about:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: This question would be improved quite a bit by having a definition of what a "powerline adapter" is.

Answer (score 4):

You can definitely plug your powerline adapter into your in wall adapter. It might take up more than one space on the in wall adapter thought preventing you from being able to use an outlet. check the sizes before you buy.

Comment: I'm not sure anything is definite about this situation. It's likely that the additional contacts reduce and degrade signal.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, and as per the usual instructions - they perform worse, or not at all plugged into a multisocket. You want it *directly* in the wall, and if losing a socket is an issue, there's passthrough versions. - for example, [netgear explicitly suggests you not do this](https://kb.netgear.com/20233/Product-FAQ-Powerline-Adapters)

In some cases - using a passthrough might also help filter noise from any device or devices plugged into it - so wall socket -> homeplug -> multisocket is a good idea.

Comment: It doesn't include wall adapter in what not to use.  Th items it excludes make sense but not a direct outlet adapter... no filtering there.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you can. The adapter doesn't much care what metal parts are between it and your service panel--even the outlets have internal contacts and screw connections.

The only concern would be if the adapter has worn or dirty contacts or introduces noise due to protection circuitry or whatever. Even clean contacts reduce signal quality somewhat.

Answer (score 0):

I do at home (the socket is behind a piece of furniture) and performs quite well